# Как получить данные с объекта класса SqlDataReader по индексу

Tags: c#, sql

```
SqlDataReader sqlReader;
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(zapros, sqlConnection);
                sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                int i = 0;
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    Arr[i, 0] = sqlReader[i].ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(Arr[i, 0]);
                }
```

Перебирается только 1 столбец таблицы
Как по индексу вытащить 2 и последующие

Comment: Менять i в цикле?

Comment: Да совершенно верно! Чет затупил